# How to Remove previous and future month date from calendar view so only current month is displayed

Tags: javascript, custom-list, css, calendar, sharepoint-calendar

I am very new to the SharePoint and hope people can help. 
I have setup a calendar and was able to apply CSS to make the calendar into weekday only.
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/fc34aa/hide-weekends-in-sharepoint-calendar-view/

However, I am trying to remove the date box for the previous and future month.
The goal is to display only the current month so it is more clean.
I tried to do some research but I couldn't find a way for it to work.

[image: Calendar Pic]

Can anyone please help to point out how to apply the CSS to achieve it?
I also saw some JavaScript method but how do I apply it? Any newbie article will be very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Picture address https://imgur.com/a/7FTiT

Comment: I have searched about your problem statement and found this solution. May be it will help you. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1fcebc04-6723-4f39-9abe-5abb2fdddf1c/how-to-disable-next-month-and-previous-month-links-in-sharepoint-2010-calendar?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to completely remove previous and next month days by CSS or JS. You can remove it by JS but when you will navigate to next or previous month days will be visible.

You can highlight these days. For example by grey color.
To do this you need to add script editor webpart and put html:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .ms-acal-outday{position: relative; z-index: 1; background-color: rgb(197,197,197); opacity: 0.5; margin-left: -1px !important; margin-right: -1px !important;}
</style>
```

It will looks like this:
[image]